# How to create a variable that uses previous (lagged) instance of its own value?

Tags: r, recursion, lag

There is a panel dataset. I have to compute a new variable:

```
cases_new = 3^(lag(cases, n=1L))
```

for the first date alone. Then the 2nd date onwards, it uses `lag` (i.e previous instance) on its own value, i.e.:

```
cases_new = 3^lag(cases_new, n=1L)
```

I tried to implement using the following code:

```
df2 <-df1 %>%
  mutate(cases_new = if_else(date == "2020-01-01", 3^(lag(cases, n=1L)), 3^(lag(cases_new, n=1L)))
```

But it threw an error stating that object 'cases_new' not found. I even tried initializing `cases_new` prior to the above assignment by:

```
df1$cases_new <- NA
```

But this did not update `cases_new` correctly (I get all NAs). Can someone help me out with this particular recursive implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve your initialization problem like this:

```r
df2 <-df1 %>%
  mutate(
    cases_new = 3^(lag(cases, n=1L)),
    cases_new = if_else(date == "2020-01-01", cases_new, 3^(lag(cases_new, n=1L)))
  )
```

BUT, I dont think that this will give you the values you want. You will have to iterate over the rows like this:

```r
cases_new <- c(3^(lag(cases, n=1L)), rep(0, nrow(df1) - 1))
for (i in 2:nrow(df1)) {
  cases_new[i] <- 3^(lag(cases_new[i - 1], n=1L))
}
df1$cases_new <- cases_new
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a slightly more complicated requirement. The lag has to be limited within each state in the panel dataset( i.e group_by(state)). So I'm at a loss for ideas on how to implement this using indices like in the method you had prescribed